# Can I use VisualStudio for editing my code in dialog-flow fulfilment?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, dialogflow-es

Just a quickie, can I use VisualStudio as the IDE for deploying my code in Dialogflow? And can I use node.js or will it have to be in C# for example?

If anyone knows a website that I can follow some steps on or if you can help me directly, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You can use any language and editor you'd like when developing fulfillment for Dialogflow.  Any language that can interact with and respond to HTTP request will be able to build fulfillment directly (and you can use other technologies to proxy HTTP request & responses to use languages that don't include a HTTP server).

- Here is the documentation for Dialogflow fulfillment:https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment
- Here a tutorial on how to get started with Dialogflow and build fulfillment: https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm rather naive with some of this and need to be pointed in the right direction!

Comment: How do I incorporate this into visual studio? I've looked through the links and there isn't any information on this. In VS, I have created a new node.js project but what code do I need to have this code speak to dialogflow? I've been googling but cant find anything :(

Comment: You'll have to setup your own server with a HTTPS address. If you're using Node.js Dialogflow has a integration with Firebase functions, a serverless solution that sets up HTTPS for you.  I'd recommend using that unless you have a good reason not to.  This tutorial goes through how to use it: https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services

Comment: @matthewayne the link is broken